# Uploading images folders from my PC to Google Colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory

I want to train a deep learning (CNN) model on a dataset containing around 100000 images. Since the dataset is huge (approx 82 Gb), I want to use Google colab since it's GPU supported. How do I upload this full image folder into my notebook and use it?
I can not use google drive or git hub since my dataset is too large.

Comment: just upload it somewhere (like kaggle) and download it from colab on each session

Answer (score 0):

You can try zipping and the unzip on collab

Step 1: Zip the whole folder

Step 2:Upload the folder

Step 3: !unzip myfoldername.zip

Step 4:type ls and see folder names to see if successful

It would be better if you compress or resize the images to reduce file size using opencv or something